# Combine mkv's in Windows (automated, not using a GUI)

Tags: windows, batch-file, mkv

From time to time I receive several mkv's from a server I have.  These mkv's are all part of the same recording, but they come in 1 minute chunks, and I don't want to have to take the time to stitch them together manually each time.  Can this be done via an automated process in Windows?

**EDIT:** See my answer below for the solution that worked for me.  The post by Endoro also looks promising.

Comment: You can use something like [mkvtoolnix](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) to combine the files.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I found a blog about mkvtoolnix that contained help for cmd.exe commands.

Comment: tell something about the file names of your 'chunks', and the structure (tracks): always the same?

Comment: I actually just finished this process successfully, however I am not allowed to answer my own question for several more hours (since I am a new user).

Comment: I corrected my code. It now collects all MKV's from the sourcefolder to one output MKV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give you an example:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%sourcefolder%"
set "line="
for %%a in (*.mkv) do set line=!line! +"%%~a"
mkvmerge -o "output.mkv" %line:~2%
```

Comment: This looks promising, but since I have not attempted it (having already solved my problem) I cannot vouch for it's effectiveness.  Has anyone else used this?

Comment: I have a long experience with command line video tools (mkvtoolnix, mp4box, ffmpeg, MPlayer, x264 ...) and yes, it works :).

Comment: this works perfectly, just has a delay while it loads the resulting line. thanks a lot.

Comment: this answer would benefit from some information about what mkvmerge is

Answer (score 3):

As I continued researching, I discovered a download page that also contained a review of mkvtoolnix (http://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html) that referred to some cmd commands he tested along with the standard GUI test.  using the "mkvmerge --help" command, I was able to determine the appropriate command to stitch mkv files together.  It looked something like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix>mkvmerge file1.mkv + file2.mkv --output C:\Users\User1\mkvfolder\combined.mkv
```

This stitched two mkv files together (that were located in the MKVToolNix folder), and puts the combined.mkv file in a different directory.  It seemed to me that changing the source directories for either of the original mkv's (file1.mkv, file2.mkv) should be possible as well, so I next tried this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix>mkvmerge file1.mkv + C:\Users\User1\Documents\file2.mkv  --output C:\Users\User1\mkvfolder\combined.mkv
```

The above code merged file1.mkv (which I had placed in the mkvtoolnix directory) with file2.mkv (which I had located in a different directory), and placed the merged file (combined.mkv) in a third directory.  The merged file ran cleanly in vlc, with no hiccups at the stitchpoint.

TL DR: go to http://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html, download MKVToolNix, and use the command line to merge mkv's.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [AVIDemux](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using%3acommand_line_usage) with the --append arg.   On this link there is also a batch file example script.