# Batch combine video files in a folder and subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, mkv

I have about 200 folders filled with MPG split files. I wanted to join files together of each folder. I found this BATCH script in other question on stackoverflow.

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%sourcefolder%"
set "line="
for %%a in (*.mpg) do set line=!line! +"%%~a"
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "Output.mkv" %line:~2%
```

[Combine mkv's in Windows (automated, not using a GUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929948/combine-mkvs-in-windows-automated-not-using-a-gui)

It works great but the problem is, i have to paste .bat file in about 200 folders and then run it about 200 times.

Can someone please help me. How can i run this file from root folder to merge/join all the files in subfolders and create new "output.mkv" file in either each subfolder or to a new folder like "/OutputVideos" with possibly a number increment in name or the same name as subfolder.

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: I have tried this batch script in several folders and it created output files as expected. Now looking for an easier and more better solution to run from root folder. If there is any.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `for /R` -- type `for /?`...

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the tip. I tried this and It combines all files of sub-folders and created a big "output.mkv" file in root. What i'm looking for is creating a separate output file for sub-folder. Any suggestion. Total newbie here. btw tried it like this `for /R %%a in (*.mpg) do set line=!line! +"%%~a"`

Comment: @wOxxOm No problem. I will be waiting for the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `for`-loop to enumerate recursively `/r` through subdirectories `/d`
- Change the working directory to the loop variable
- Enumerate the `.mpg` files and concatenate the names in a variable (use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html))
- Invoke `mkvmerge` with that variable (note that it starts with a space and `+` so we should extract its contents starting with index 2, the index is 0-based which means that the first character has index `0` and the third character we need has index `2`)

Put the code in `concatenate.bat` file in the base folder, the batch file will process all subfolders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set mkvmerge="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"

for /d /r %%D in (*) do (
    pushd %%D
    set files=
    for %%F in (*.mpg) do set files=!files! + ^( "%%F" ^)
    if not "!files!"=="" %mkvmerge% -o "output.mkv" !files:~2!
    popd
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33044477), but I find it faster to as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /b /s /ad') do (
    set files=
    if exist %%d\*.mpg (
      pushd %%d
      for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "%%d\*.mpg"') do (
        set files=!files! "%%f"
      )
    echo !files!
    popd
    )
)
```

Ideally, scan once only subfolders and keep only the non duplicate paths.

Comment: What exactly is faster here? 99.9999999999999999% of time is spent in `mkvmerge`. Also why `dir` parsing? It's not needed for this task. And what duplicate paths are you talking about?

Comment: @wOxxOm 1) I agree with you that mkmerge takes 99.9%. but on tasks such as merging text, and thousands of folders, the speed will suffer. 3) That's assuming I use a single loop to search for the file ".mpg" and I extract the folder path, I meant that I do not know how to do without duplicate occurrences.